# Access property of generic type not defined in interface using dynamic

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I'm having to modify a lot of code to set a SqlCe database connection for a bunch of table adapters. I would like to avoid the duplication involved and minimise the chance I've missed updating a table adapter by creating a generic method to wrap the creation of each table adapter. Unfortunately the table adapters aren't derived from a single base class and each has it's own *Connection* property. By assigning the new table adapter to *dynamic* I can get it to compile. Is this a good approach and are there any traps I should be aware of when using *dynamic*?

```
protected void TableAdapter<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IDisposable, new()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (dynamic tableAdapter = new T())
    {
        tableAdapter.Connection = connection;
        action(tableAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah, no traps. I think you are exchanging a compiler check for improved readability. And if someone else uses it wrong the runtime error will be obvious that the `Connection` member isn't there.

Personally, I would also add the cast to the argument of the action, because the dynamic invocation there shouldn't be necessary. But i consider that an optional choice because the performance gain is probably negligible, it's going to work the same either way, my person style is to limit the scope of dynamic use to purposeful.

```
protected void TableAdapter<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IDisposable, new()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (dynamic tableAdapter = new T())
    {
        tableAdapter.Connection = connection;
        action((T)tableAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it's a bit unorthodox for C#.  Here is one alternative that sacrifices a bit of DRY for compile-time safety:

```
protected void TableAdapter<T>(Action<T, SqlCeConnection> action) where T : IDisposable, new()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var tableAdapter = new T())
    {
        action(tableAdapter, connection);
    }
}
```

Now your action will need to set the Connection in addition to whatever else it does, but the compiler verifies the access and you don't have the performance penalty of the dynamic wrapper.

Comment: Thanks Dan, yes I had considered that approach but I figure I'm more likely to forget to set the connection in the action than call TableAdapter against something other than a table adapter.